# How can i get a response code of httprequest using java script?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xmlhttprequest, domdocument

My need is to get response code the web page using java script. I have to inject this java script in current loading page and get the response code. Is that possible?

Comment: share your code and you are using ajax for this purpose?

Comment: @waqas

<Script>

if (document.addEventListener) { <br>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getExistingPageResponseCode, false); <br>
} <br>

function getExistingPageResponseCode() { <br>
  // need to find the response status code of the current page, as this function will execute after page load. <br>
}<br>

I will inject this script via BHO (Browser Helper Object) to existing webpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i wrote a IE browser extension to return responsecode once the page is loaded.

Written BHO using VC++ refering

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489(v=vs.85).aspx

added listener for events OnDocumentComplete (DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE),OnNavigateError(DISPID_NAVIGATEERROR) of DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2

now i can able to get pointer of IWebBrowser2 during document complete and navigation error events and also Response code from OnNavigateError->StatusCode->lval.

using IWebBrowser i can append my content to existing webpage after page load and during navigation error.

Answer (score 0):

```
function httpGet(){    
var url = "test.aspx";
var xmlHttp = null;
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false);
xmlHttp.send( null );
alert(xmlHttp.responseText);}

Try this one.
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, unfortunately this not the solution i am expecting, i want know the response status of the web page where i place my java script